# Type Synonyms in FSharp

Tags: f#, domain-driven-design

If I declare a type in FSharp like this:

```
type Dog = {Id:int;Name;String}
```

and I want to create a synonym in the code base

```
type Pooch = {Id:int;Name;String}
```

and I want to use either type interchangably.  Sometimes "Dog" and sometimes "Pooch".  I was thinking of doing somekind of OO technique where Pooch inherits from Dog -> though in reality Dog can inherit for Pooch just as a Pooch can inherit from Dog.

Is there a language construct that allows type synonyms in FSharp?  Does any language support it?  Note that this example goes against all software engineering rules where you should only use one word to represent one thing :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think I just answered my own question

```
type Dog = {Id:int; Name:string}
type Pooch = Dog
```

Thanks

Comment: You found it. That's a type alias.